# Flexslider with Background Images - Issue

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

i created a jsfiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/qw1uozpj/

During the next slide comes a white line appears:

The problem is, that i use background-size: cover

My CSS:

```
.flexslider {
    width: 600px;
}

.flexslider li div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

I tried different adaptions to my CSS but nothing works.

Comment: Adding `background:#000;` to `.slides`, not enought??

Comment: But i have bright and dark pictures

Comment: When `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` change we see flash of background (rerender,reflow of elements).
If you can, use slider that not use `transform`, but use `margin-left` or etc.